# Remove one vocal from a conversation

Tags: audacity, adobe-audition

I have two audio tracks, Audio1 and Audio2.
Audio1 has voice of **Host**
and Audio2 contains the voice of **Guest** plus the voice of the host(same as Audio1)

Now, is there anyway to utilize Audio1 to omit the **host's** sound from Audio2, and leaving the Guest voice alone.

Answer (score -1):

If Host's sound absolutely the same in both tracks. Use Phase invert on audio1 and add it with audio2.

But it's probably was recorded with different mics so it won't work that perfectly. You'll need to adjust phase and volume to made silence.

Comment: Your answers should remain strictly answers; please do not promote your web site here. You are free to link to your site in your profile if you like. See also our [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)